# Terraform resource based on condition stage variable string

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I am trying to attach a different type of policy to a user in each of my three environments:
dev, staging and production.

The environment information is stored as a terraform variable in string format, e.g. 'dev'.

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "s3-dev-policy" {
  count       = var.stage != "dev" ? 1 : 0
  name        = "s3-bucket-policy-${var.stage}"
  description = "Access rights for cicd-user to Bucket on Dev"

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3::: dev-bucket-pushed",
                "arn:aws:s3::: dev-bucket-pushed/*"
            ]
        }
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "attach_cicd-users_s3_dev_group_policy" {
  count      = var.stage != "dev" ? 1 : 0
  group      = aws_iam_group.cicd-users.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.s3-dev-policy[count.index]
}
```

Terraform apply does not complain about the syntax but it does not apply this resource either even though the stage is set to 'dev'. Does the conditional only work with boolean as a data type?

Comment: This should work if you are 100% sure that `var.stage` is `dev` - are you sure that the infra. hasn't already been provisioned and that Terraform is skipping over actually applying since there is nothing to apply?

Comment: Exactly. `terraform state list` might help you assess what's already managed by Terraform.

Comment: Also - are you sure the policy text is right? I am unsure about the space after colons, i.e. `::: `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **condition is incorrect**, policy has **syntax errors**, **arn is incorrect**, among other problems. It all should be:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "s3-dev-policy" {
  count       = var.stage == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  name        = "s3-bucket-policy111-${var.stage}"
  description = "Access rights for cicd-user to Bucket on Dev"

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::dev-bucket-pushed",
                "arn:aws:s3:::dev-bucket-pushed/*"
            ]
        }
       ] 
}
EOF
}


resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "attach_cicd-users_s3_dev_group_policy" {
  count      = var.stage == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  group      = aws_iam_group.cicd-users.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.s3-dev-policy[count.index].arn
}
```

Comment: Haha, thank you the condition was indeed wrong. My bad. I also added arn. The syntax error was only due to deleting something in the example. It works now.
What were the 'other issues' you were referring to?